# Multi step loop to acquire weather data over years and stations

Tags: r, download, rnoaa

I have a process to create a df for a single weather station over a singular month period. However, I have about 25 stations that I would like to aquire precipitation data for over a 5 year period.

I have the station ids in a df, that looks like the table below (but with 23 more stations.

```
stationid           County
GHCND:USW00093721   ANNEARUNDEL
GHCND:USC00182308   BALTIMORE
```

The weather dataset is aquired through the following code

```
library("rnoaa")
ANNEARUNDEL_2006 <- ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', stationid = "GHCND:USC00182060", datatypeid='PRCP', startdate = '2006-07-01', enddate = '2006-08-01', limit=400, token =  "API KEY") 

ANNEARUNDEL_2006 <- ANNEARUNDEL_2006$data
```

I familiar with very basic for loops that work for one process. Is there a way to set this up the loop would create a new df using the county name and year over the span of 2006 to 2011 for all 25 stations? Is a loop the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like loops for things like this because they are easier to read and write. You could do it like this with two loops:

```
my_df <- read.table(text = "stationid   County
GHCND:USW00093721   ANNEARUNDEL
GHCND:USC00182308   BALTIMORE",
                    header = T)

library(rnoaa)

results <- list() # list as storage variable for the loop results
i <- 1 # indexing variable

for(sid in unique(my_df$stationid)) { # each station in your stationid dataframe
    for(year in 2006:2011) { # each year you care about
        data <- ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', stationid = sid,
                     datatypeid='PRCP', startdate = paste0(year, '-01-01'),
                     enddate = paste0(year, '-12-31'), limit=400, token = "API KEY")$data # subset the returned list right away here with $data

        # add info from each loop iteration
        data$county <- my_df[my_df$stationid == sid,]$County
        data$year <- year

results[[i]] <- data # store it
i <- i + 1 # rinse and repeat
    }
}
one_big_df <- do.call(rbind, results) # stack all of the data frames together rowwise
```

Of course, you could always adjust a for loop to using `lapply` or it's friends. If speed became an issue you might want to consider it.

Comment: I do really like how easy to read this is. I ran this exactly as you had it, and I'm getting an error. The error is "Error in vapply(elements, encode, character(1)) : 
  values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[8]]) result is length 13". I'm not exactly sure what this means. Would you happen to know?

Comment: yea it's because of my typo in the `ncdc()` line! I fixed it, try it now

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this.  Set up a function to read in the data, then loop through your df with `mapply`, and for each year with `lapply`.  The output will be a named list of data (vectors as it stands, although you could capture more columns of `df` if you wanted, in which case they would be dataframes).

```
getNCDC <- function(id,County,year){
  df <- ncdc(datasetid='GHCND', stationid = id, datatypeid='PRCP', startdate = paste0(year,'-07-01'), enddate = paste0(year,'-08-01'), limit=400, token =  "API KEY") 
  df <- list(df$data)
  names(df) <- paste(County,year,sep="_")
  return(df)
}

allData <- lapply(2006:2011,function(year) mapply(getNCDC,df$stationid,df$County,year))
```

Answer (score 2):

The following solution uses funcitons from the `rnoaa` and `tidyverse` package.

Notice that I used the `ghcnd_search` to download the precipitation data.

```
# Load packages
library(rnoaa)
library(tidyverse)

# Create example data frame
sample_df <- data.frame(stationid = c("USW00093721", "USC00182308"),
                        County = c("ANNEARUNDEL", "BALTIMORE"),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Download the data use map. 
data_list <- map(sample_df$stationid, ghcnd_search, 
                 date_min = "2006-01-01", date_max = "2011-12-31", var = "prcp")
```

Now the `prcp` data from each station are downloaded as a data frame. They are all stroed in the `data_list` as a list.

You can access the data of each station by accessing the list, or you can convert the data in the list to a single data frame. Here is an example:

```
# Transpost the data_list. Turns a list-of-lists "inside-out"
data_list2 <- transpose(data_list)

# Combine all data to a single data frame
data_df <- bind_rows(data_list2$prcp)
```

Now all the data are in `data_df` as a data frame